# "Ist das" used with masculine/feminine and plurals?

Tags: gender, article

Working through Schaum's German Grammar and they ask to turn "Ist das dein Kind" into the plural.  The answer:

Sind das deine Kinder.

Why isn't it "Sind die deine Kinder" or "Sind sie deine Kinder", likewise, it's "Ist das dein Hund" versus "ist er dein Hund".

In this case gender is not followed - are there others?

Comment: C.f.: Is this your wife/ is she your wife?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I like to mention, that both your sentences are correct. Other variations on the question would be

> Sind jene Deine Kinder?
>   Sind dies Deine Kinder?

In this case, "das" ist not used as an article, but as a pronoun. Actually, a more complete version of the question would be

> Sind das dort Deine Kinder?

Similar to

> Sind dies dort Deine Kinder?

The same reasoning applies to the dog. You can basically reference anything by *das/dies* similiar to *that/this* in English.

Comment: You should mention that "Sind jene Deine Kinder" is technically possible (no grammar mistake) but you have to try really hard to find a situation in real life where this sentence would occur. Most likely in a very old novel or so (19th century). Nobody would speak or write that way today.

Comment: And note that the subject is *dein Kind*, so subject and verb are in agreement in all of the examples.

Comment: No, he asked specifically about the plural form *deine Kinder*

Comment: I’m not sure the question of gender agreement applies: ‘das’ is used as a demonstrative, and demonstratives don’t really have genders. You can (point and) say ‘Das ist mein Kind’, but also ‘Das ist mein Mann/meine Frau’. To be sure, one *can* use ‘er’/'sie'/'es' demonstratively and thus have a gendered demonstrative; but in many contexts, that'd be as odd as ‘Is *he* your son?’
Note that although ‘deine Kinder’ is plural, ‘Sind das deine Kinder?’ seems more natural than ‘Sind diese Deine Kinder?’ I’d only use the pl. ‘diese’ in a *complex* demonstrative, like ‘Diese Bücher gehören Paul’.

Answer (score 2):

"Das" is just the placeholder subject in German. But the "complement" is plural, consisting of multiple "Kinder."

Because of that fact, you use the plural form of the verb, "sind," and not "ist" in the sentence.

If you were writing about, say, a woman, you would write "Das *ist eine* Dame."

As another poster pointed out, you can also use certain similar words in place of "das." such as "dies." His other suggestion, "jene," appears to be an uncommon usage.